# PHP: Can an object access protected parameters in an object which derives from the same super class?

Tags: php

Say you have some class `Base` with say a property: `protected $foo` and you have two subclasses `ChildA` and `ChildB` who both extend `Base`.

Can an object of `ChildA` read `ChildB->foo`?

I've run into a bug with doctrine lazy loading that I can only assume is due to this behavior. It seems counter to how I understand the `protected` keyword from other languages but I can't figure out how else I would be getting the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Well, why don't you simply test this? You make a 10 line script and have the answer...

Comment: Read in what way? Does `ChildA` have a property of type `ChildB` so you want to know if it can call `$this->b->foo`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, just implement a simple test script and have the answer:

```
<?php
class Base { 
  protected $foo;
  public function Base($value) {
    $this->foo = $value;
  }
  public function getFoo($obj) {
    return $obj->foo;
  } 
}
class ChildA extends Base{};
class ChildB extends Base{};

$a = new ChildA("A");
$b = new ChildB("B");
var_dump($b->getFoo($a));
```

The output is:

```
string(1) "A"
```

The same is true if you implement the accessing method in the child class, so this is not a binding issue.

So the answer is "yes, that is possible".

But I assume that is not what you actually wanted to know, just what you asked. If you *really* want to know if the object of class ChildB somehow treats the property of the object of class ChildA as own property and can directly access it, then the answer is "no", since those are separate objects.

Comment: No, i was really just asking about the properties visability to the other object, not if it inherited the same property or something like that. I'm just having a weird interaction because of this quirk

Comment: As said: that is not possible, since the object of class ChildB does not even have a handle for the property of class ChildA. So how should it access that property? But that does not mean that the object cannot access it at all.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is impossible due to incapsulation. Protected methods/properties are visible only for classes which are `derived` from super class (i.e. parent). `ChildB` is not a parent of `ChildA`. They are siblings.

```php
class Base {
  protected $foo;
}

class ChildA extends Base { 
  public function setFoo($foo) {
    $this->foo = $foo;
  }
}

class ChildB extends Base {
  public function getFoo() {
    return $this->foo;
  }
}

$childB = new ChildB();
$childA = new ChildA();
$childA->setFoo($childB->getFoo());
```

Answer (score 0):

**No** The only way to archive that is by creating a `get_foo()` method in the parent class as follows

```
<?php
  Class Base {
    protected $foo = 'protected';
    function get_foo(){
     return $this->foo;
    }
  }
 Class ChildA extends Base {}
 Class ChildB extends Base {}
 $childA = new ChildA();
 echo $childA->get_foo();
?>
```